# Connected App OAuth scopes settings have no effect

Tags: oauth2, authentication, connected-apps, community

I have a Connected App in Org A, which is used to let their users log into Community B in Org B.
The registration handler works fine, but only the OAuth scopes inside the Connected App are not considered.

Here are my settings in Org A's Connected App (yes, I waited more than 10 minutes to be sure). It includes "Access and Manage your Chatter data":

[image: OAuth Scopes for Connected App]

This is what users are presented when logging to the Community B, coming from Org A through the Connected App. It only shows "Access your basic information":

[image: OAuth Scopes shown to user]

So.... maybe it is just not presented to the user, but in the background I could use the AccessToken to access some Chatter data? Unfortunately, also here it says that I am missing one of the three required OAuth scopes to do this:

[image: REST Client return 401 Unauthorized when trying to access the Chatter Endpoint]

Am I missing some setting, or don't I understand the concept behind Connected Apps and OAuth scopes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OAuth scopes you select in your Connected App only define which ones your Connected App is allowed to request - you still have to actually request them to be able to use them.

You can [change the default scopes requested in your Authentication Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm&language=en_US). You'll want to add `chatter_api` at the very least to achieve what you want.

Comment: that worked! I must have missed that point in the docs, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like your changes fully replicated.   Has it corrected itself yet?

Comment: The answer from Alex Tennant did the trick! Thanks for following up :)